# In Visual Studio, what is the keyboard shortcut and Command ID to "search/query everything box"

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

In Visual Studio 2021 or above what is the keyboard shortcut (KeyMap) Command ID to the "search everything box"? This box is displayed top right of IDE menu bar. It offers a global search including, IDE actions, menus, commands and symbols within code.
The default Ctrl+Q is NOT assigned on my config, used for something else.
Please see the screenshot:

[image]

Could not find the correct command in [KeyMap](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/default-keyboard-shortcuts-in-visual-studio?view=vs-2022). For information, in JetBrains Rider, this command is called "Search Everywhere".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On my installation of VS 2022 the placeholder text within the search box is "Search (Ctrl+Q)".
[image: VS 2022 quick launch input]

Pressing this shortcut in the keyboard mappings yields the Shortcut Window.QuickLaunch

[image: VS 2022 keyboard shortcut mapping showing Window.QuickLaunch as shortcut activated by Ctrl+Q]

The page you linked to also shows this is the default settings for Window.QuickLaunch.

Answer (score 1):

According to Visual Studio [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/visual-studio-search?view=vs-2019#:%7E:text=The%20search%20results%20includes%20tabs,%2C%20options%2C%20components%2C%20and%20templates)

Use the **Ctrl+Q** keyboard shortcut to access the search box

[image]

**Advance Shortcuts:**

The search results include tabs for All, Code, Visual Studio. You can save time by using the following keyboard shortcuts for different types of searches:

**Ctrl+Q, Ctrl+T** for files, types, and members
**Ctrl+Q, Ctrl+M** for Visual Studio menus, options, components, and templates
**Ctrl+Q, Ctrl+E** to go to the All tab, for both

Comment: Unfortunately on mine this does not work. Can you please provide the KeyMap Command ID?

Comment: sure, let me edit the response

Answer (score 0):

Please try with `Ctrl+Q` it is working fine in visual studio 2022.

[image]